# Conjugation: Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $E$.

Then for conjugations:
$$C:E\to E:\quad C^2=1\implies\|C\|=1$$

How can I check this?

Comment: what is the definition of conjugation?

Comment: @Norbert: Simply that $C^2=1$. *(I think I already have a counterexample but please go ahead.)*

Comment: Is $C$ required to be linear?

Comment: @hardmath: Yes, I'm sorry, I forget about that: $C$ is linear.

Comment: If C is linear this is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$
C:\mathbb{R}_2^2\to\mathbb{R}_2^2:(x,y)\mapsto(2x+y,-3x-2y)
$$
Then $\Vert C((1,1))\Vert>\Vert(1,1)\Vert$

Comment: Yep, it may be even unbounded in infinite dimensional Banach spaces. Anyway, thank you!! :) (+1)

Comment: Also, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ take $a \neq 0$ and $|a| \neq 1$, then map $(x,y) \mapsto (ay,a^{-1}x)$.  This can be generalized to an "even number" of dimensions (including infinite).